# Open txt file from desktop using PHP

Tags: php

It is possible to open a txt file from desktop to my webserver?
I have tried `fopen` but It cant open the stream.

Code:

```
$txtfile = fopen("C:\Users\steve\Desktop\AntiCheat.txt","r");
echo $txtfile;
```

The Error message:

```
Warning: fopen(C:\Users\steve\Desktop\AntiCheat.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

This works fine If I using `XAMPP` but on my webserver it does not works

Comment: Does your web server reside on the same Windows computer as the file?

Comment: No, but If I'm using `<input type="file">` the file can be uploaded by clicking the button but I dont want it so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This works fine If I using XAMPP but on my webserver it does not works

XAMPP is a package that includes a web server, so presumably, you mean that it doesn't work if you use a web server that is running **on a different computer**.

This shouldn't be a surprise as the other computer won't have your hard disk in it, so it won't have your C drive or your files.

You need to either:

- Share your file over the network to the computer running the web server (since the web server probably doesn't run on your LAN, this is likely to be logistically challenging).
- Copy the file to the computer running the web server.